# Web-Scraping Python, Indexing Issue for DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, web-scraping

I'm working on a web-scraper for Spotify Charts to extract the top 200 daily songs each day. I have done everything to extract the data I'm interested in including rank, artist, track title, and stream numbers. What I'm stuck on is putting everything into a DataFrame to export as a CSV to excel. Right now when I print my DataFrame, it is treating each cycle as 1 row with 4 columns as opposed to 200 rows with 4 columns.

I'm not sure what the issue is as I've tried just about everything and looked into it as much as I could. I know something is wrong with the indexing because each "what should be a row" has the same first "0" index, when they should go sequential to 199. Also, the column names for my DataFrame keep repeating after each "what should be a row", so I know there is definitely an issue there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date, timedelta
from time import time
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base_url = 'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/global/daily/'

r = requests.get(base_url)



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
chart = soup.find('table', {'class': 'chart-table'})
tbody = chart.find('tbody')
for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):

    rank_text = []
    rank_text_elem = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table- 
    position'})
    for item in rank_text_elem:
        rank_text = []
        rank_text.append(item)

    artist_text = []
    artist_text_elem = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table- 
    track'}).find_all('span')
    for item in artist_text_elem:
        artist_text = []
        artist_text.append(item.text.replace('by ','').strip())

    title_text = []
    title_text_elem = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table- 
    track'}).find_all('strong')
    for item in title_text_elem:
        title_text = []
        title_text.append(item.text)

    streams_text = []
    streams_text_elem = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table-streams'})
    for item in streams_text_elem:
        streams_text = []
        streams_text.append(item)

# creating dataframe to store 4 variables 

    list_of_data = list(zip(rank_text, artist_text, title_text, 
    streams_text))

    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data, columns = 
    ['Rank','Artist','Title','Streams'])
    print(df)
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a dataframe to hold 4 variables in each row for 200 rows for each date of spotify global charts. Please ignore some of the modules and libraries I've included at the top, they are used for iterating through each page of the historical data based on dynamic urls which I have already figured out. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please try to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem.

Comment: @akilat90 i just added the code for the other variables. I hope that helps with what you were looking for! If not, please point me in the right direction. I think I have included everything necessary in the code.

Comment: Your issue is ```list_of_data = list(zip(rank_text, artist_text, title_text, 
    streams_text))```. You have a single list which will just make a single row. Make it an array (using np.array() over the zip instead of list), then call reshape to make it the shape you want.

Comment: `list_of_data` keeps only one row - you should keep this row in list `all_rows` and use `dataframe(all_rows)` after `for` loop, not inside.

Comment: @BenPap thanks for the suggestion. I just tried implementing this and I'm getting an error "cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (200,4). "

Comment: @furas i just tried this and the output gave me only the last entry for each date.

Comment: you have to keep all data on list `all_rows.append(list_of_data)` and use `DataFrame(all_rows)` AFTER `for` loop, NOT inside `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `for` loop I create list `all_rows`.

Inside `for` loop I add list with single row of data to `all_rows`.

After `for` loop I use `all_rows` to create `DataFrame`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/global/daily/'

r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
chart = soup.find('table', {'class': 'chart-table'})
tbody = chart.find('tbody')

all_rows = []

for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):

    rank_text = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table-position'}).text

    artist_text = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table-track'}).find('span').text
    artist_text = artist_text.replace('by ','').strip()

    title_text = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table-track'}).find('strong').text

    streams_text = tr.find('td', {'class': 'chart-table-streams'}).text

    all_rows.append( [rank_text, artist_text, title_text, streams_text] )

# after `for` loop

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['Rank','Artist','Title','Streams'])
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` and `requests`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url ='https://spotifycharts.com/regional/global/daily/'

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers).content

table = pd.read_html(r)[0] #transfer html to pandas
table.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all', inplace = True) #drop nan column
table[['Title','Artist']] = table['Unnamed: 3'].str.split(' by ',expand=True) #split title artist strings into two columns
del table['Unnamed: 3'] #remove combined column
table = table[['Track', 'Artist','Title', 'Unnamed: 4']] #re-order cols
table.columns= ['Rank', 'Artist','Title', 'Streams'] #rename cols
print(table)
```